# Unable to install lullabot/amp and sensiolabs/security-checker

Tags: 7, theming, drush, configuration, composer

i have installed amp and composer manager
today i have been trying to get lullabot/amp installed, i have managed to install composer and drush on my computer but im not sure if they have been installed correctly. The image below shows that they are not installed. This is on my localhost/xampp would that make any difference. Could someone help me get this right as its a big learning curve as i have never used composer or drush since today. Any ideas on how to get this working.
[image]

Comment: Not quite. This image shows that you have not yet installed several PHP libraries. Composer is a PHP dependency manager, which you needed to download these libraries for you. I suppose you should be able to do something as `drush composer-manager update --no-dev` do actually have composer download these libraries for you. (Refer to the composer managers documentation for the correct command if this one does not work, it has been a while since I last used it).

Comment: Thank you for your information, could i just ask, when i use drush composer-manager update --no-dev do i run this in the root of my website or a particular folder, as i am not 100% confident with composer or drush

Comment: Your Drupal root should be fine. Alternatively you can navigate to the folder containing your composer.json file (see the composer manager settings for this folder) and run 'composer update --no-dev'.

Comment: Ok i tried and failed.

Comment: Read the composer manager documentation it is there as well.

Comment: Error.  the drush command composer-manager update could not be found.

Comment: You can run `drush cc drush` to get it picked up, if it doesn't work after that you might not have the Composer Manager module downloaded/in the right place

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands, in this order:
1. Go to the docroot and type: drush composer-json-rebuild
2. In the same place: drush composer-manager install
3. If this doesn't work, go to sites/default/files/composer and type: composer install
4. In the end you can run: drush composer-manager update